# BOTW: Getting hit by a comet

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Does any player ever got hit by a falling comet in the game?

If so, any links to images or videos are appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason behind this request? Do you have any reason to believe this occurs sometimes?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, because I thought it would be funny if it had happened at some time

Comment: in that case please place questions like this in the chat or simply ask google, the SX sites are for solving problem together. Unless you have a specific reason why you want to be able to get hit by a comet, this is not the site to ask this

Comment: I think it's possible to word this into a valid question. There are comets in the game, and it's known that there are shooting stars for a quest line https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2018-03-02-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-xenoblade-chronicles-quest-largest-bridge-skulls-left-eye-snowy-mountain-shooting-star-locations-4857

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! Well-received questions here show research effort, are clear, and are useful. While the question is somewhat clear and technically on topic, it is not useful at all and does not show any research effort. I anticipate this is why the question has received so many downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible. Falling stars do not spawn in random world coordinates - this means that you can't be at the right place at the right time and have a meteor fall onto you. Instead, falling stars spawn at random times in a location relative to Link pretty far away.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfHRjIW21GQ) shows multiple attempts to get hit by a falling star, all failing. [This forum thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75579575) also asks about getting hit by falling stars, again with no success.